# Spring Boot race condition on updating same entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

For spring boot, i understand that if I have a function that say, to reduce balance of user, we can use @Transactional annotation like below in a service method:

```
@Transactional
public void reduceBalance(long userId, BigDecimal usage) {
    ...
}
```

But my question isn't referring at placing control at specific function, I'm wondering below:

```
public void updateAge(long userId, int newAge) {
    User theUser = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(null); // Line A-1
    theUser.setAge(newAge); // Line A-2
    userRepository.save(theUser); // Line A-3
}

public void updateName(long userId, String newName) {
    User theUser = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(null); // Line B-1
    theUser.setName(newName); // Line B-2
    userRepository.save(theUser); // Line B-3
}
```

Let say if 2 requests comes in at exactly same time, Line A-1 and B-1 is executed at same time, follow by A-2 and B-2, then A-3 and B-3.

Will B-3 overwrite A-2 changes? If yes, does it means we should be putting @Transactional annotation almost in every services, or is there actually a better design?

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommendable use @Transaction in each service but if you want to manage by different ways to do it, 
Other way is using @Version annotation

```
 Specifies the version field or property of an entity class that
 serves as its optimistic lock value.  The version is used to ensure
 integrity when performing the merge operation and for optimistic
 concurrency control.
```

Comment: Thank you for the insights, it seems that your profile shows you have absolutely in-depth knowledge on spring boot JPA framework, may I ask you some questions please? So based on the question, B-3 overwriting A-2 is confirmed right? if we put @Transactional annotation in each function, does it means, if A-1 is followed by B-1, B-1 will be pausing until all A-1~3 is executed? So sorry for asking because these race conditions seems too hard to be tested..

Comment: Anytime  I could test your conditions, first since a request enters to controllers, by definition and default Spring manages any bean created as Singleton, i.e. all components, then you should not worry about it because it will be in order to arrive and never both requests come at the same time, then one request enters to queue and the second one as well and they will be doing logic in order to arrive as I mentioned. You might worry when you use static things, there are always problems, Then we can say that the last one will override.

Comment: If you want to test this scenario, the create a stress test concurrently, I might recommend to use Gatling with Scala, it is easy to create, you will see that it is so hard to simulate the same time, but that test will stress it and put on your logs, and check the result so in database logs as your applications logs. Check the time if you will be millisconds the difference when they come. Kind regards.